# Chrome JS/CSS cache with regards to --no-sandbox switch

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, browser-cache, sandbox

Basically, what I would like to learn is to how the Chrome's JS/CSS cache works with regards to `--no-sandbox` command line switch.

To be more precise, it's not clear to me whether the browser is allowed to cache JS and CSS files locally while running with and without that key.

Comment: Your question is quite vague. Specific questions tend to get specific answers. If possible, try to make your question more specific.

Comment: @mtak Thanks, tried to clarify as much as possible.